# Delete or Cancel DragShadow

Tags: android

I have a custom relative layout where i can drag and drop some 
buttons. I start the Dragging in my onTouch:

```
/**
 * 
 */
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN : {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)view;
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(imageButton);

            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            view.performClick();
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

As you can see i create a DragShadow. I now have a small problem with it because i defined a drag area. When the user drags the button out of the drag area the dragging gets cancelled:

```
    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {
        View sourceView = (View) event.getLocalState();

        float sourceX = sourceView.getX();
        float sourceY = sourceView.getY();
        float dropX = event.getX() - (sourceView.getWidth() / 2);
        float dropY = event.getY() - (sourceView.getHeight() / 2);

        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED : {
                TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(dropX - sourceX, 0, dropY - sourceY, 0);
                animation.setDuration(300);

                sourceView.startAnimation(animation);
                sourceView.setX(sourceX);
                sourceView.setY(sourceY);
                sourceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP : {
                sourceView.setX(dropX);
                sourceView.setY(dropY);
                sourceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(dropX - sourceX, 0, dropY - sourceY, 0);
                animation.setDuration(300);

                sourceView.startAnimation(animation);
                sourceView.setX(sourceX);
                sourceView.setY(sourceY);
            } break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

So when the user leaves the drag area the button gets automatically moved back to its original position using an animation. The problem is that the DragShadow is still visible and i cant find a method to delete or cancel the DragShadow. The DragShadow is visible as long as the user touches the screen.

So how can i programmatically cancel or delete the DragShadow when the ACTION_DRAG_EXITED is triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this.  The sad truth of Android's drag shadow is that it can't be changed once created. (I ran into this when trying to create a drag shadow that was visually responsive to other views).  You have two options:

1: The easiest solution would be to to not try to cancel the drag on ACTION_DRAG_EXITED. It goes against Android's design pattern to do so, and seems like it might be annoying to the user.  Unless you have a good reason to need this functionality, I'd say leave it out.

Edit:  I had previously said that you can check to see if the drop point is in the view.  There's an easier way to accomplish this:

ACTION_DRAG_ENDED gets sent when the user drops the shadow, regardless of whether it's in the view that is listening to the drag events.  ACTION_DROP will also get sent if it's released in the listening view.

So what you would want to do is just have the code to move the button to its new location on ACTION_DROP, and have the animation run on ACTION_DRAG_ENDED.  The animation will get run whether or not the button gets moved to a new location.

2:  Roll your own drag and drop code.  It's not crazy difficult, there are lots of tutorials, and it opens up a world of possibilities (multi-finger drag and drop, e.g.) if you're willing to go down rabbit holes.  I've found it to be a good learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in nothing here when you create your shadowBuilder:

```
View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder();
```